# How to create a list of columns using a conditions dynamically?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input Data Frame is

[image: check the image]

Below is My code for creating Multiple columns as per my single column data, if my column contains 'reporting' that should be column name as well as it will be place one if reporting contains in that column.

am getting correct output but I want this code dynamical way is any another ways...

```
df['reporting']=pd.np.where((df['Name'].str.contains('reporting',regex=False)),1,0)
df['update']=pd.np.where((df['Name'].str.contains('update',regex=False)),1,0)
df['offer']=pd.np.where((df['Name'].str.contains('offer',regex=False)),1,0)
df['line']=pd.np.where((df['Name'].str.contains('line',regex=False)),1,0)
```

Output:

[image: Expected out put dynamically]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for get all value sof list with `\b\b` for words boundaries, join them by `|` and pass to [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
L = ["reporting","update","offer","line"]
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)

df = df.join(df['Name'].str.findall(pat).str.join('|').str.get_dummies())
```

Or processing each column separately, here `np.where` is not necessary, convert `True,False` to `1,0` by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) or [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
for c in L:
    df[c] = df['Name'].str.contains(c, regex=False).astype(int)
```

---

```
for c in L:
    df[c] = df['Name'].str.contains(c, regex=False).view('i1')
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, now my code is working dynamical way...

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of keywords, iterate the list and create new columns?

```
keywords = ["reporting","update","offer","line"]

for word in keywords:
    df[word]=pd.np.where((df['Name'].str.contains(word,regex=False)),1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks Arther, now my code is working dynamical way...